# How to get child transactions?

Tags: transaction, iri-legacy-api

What is the best way to get all children of a certain transaction using any of the IOTA libraries/the IOTA API?
By children of a transaction, I mean all transactions that **directly** reference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [findTransactions](https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/reference#findtransactions) 
 and pass the hash of the "certain" transaction in the `approvees` parameter:

```
curl http://localhost:14265 \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' \
  -d '{"command": "findTransactions", "approvees": ["YOUR9HASH9HERE9..."]}'
```

All IOTA libraries (Java, JS, Go, etc.) provide a convenience method with the same name and parameters.